# Difficult examples of invertible, differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples, inverse

Give an example of:

1)$f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $f$ is invertible in some neighbourhood of $x_0$ (that is $f$ is locally invertible) but $|Jf(x)|=0$ (jacobian determinant) $\forall x$ in the neighbourhood of $x_0$

2)$f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $f$ is invertible and differentiable in some neighbourhood of $x_0$, continuous differentiable in $x_0$ but $J|f(x)|=0$ $\forall x$ in the neighbourhood of $x_0$

3)$f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $f$ is differentiable in the neighbourhood of $x_0$, $|Jf(x)|\neq 0$ $\forall x$ in the neighbourhood of $x_0$ but $f$ is not invertible in any neighboourhood of $x$ $\forall x\in V_\alpha({x_0})$ (neighbourhood of $x_0$)

Unfortunately I haven´t been able to give examples of such fucntions; I think that this functions are "very pathological",and I would really appreciate if you can help me with this problem

Comment: Doesn't 3) contradict the [inverse function theorem](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/) for non-$C^1$ maps?

Comment: I have the hypothesis of the inverse function theorem as follows: $f$ is differentiable in some neighbourhood of $x_0$ $|Jf(x)|\neq 0$ and $f$ is continous differentiable in $x_0$, I haven´t seen an statement of the theorem without the continous differentiable hypothesis

Comment: Now you have seen it, because I linked to it. Which shows there is no function as in 3).

Comment: You are right, my bad so number 3) can´t happen thanks a lot @2mkgz